# Enviar sitemap.php (no XML) a Google

Tags: .htaccess, sitemap

No sé si el proceso de enviar el sistemap en formato PHP varía algo con respecto al XML. Lo he subido a Google pero me aparece un error:

> Tu sitemap parece ser una página HTML. un formato de sitemap compatible.

No he encontrado demasiada información para estos casos. Lo que he hecho es generar el sitemap con PHP, lo guardo como sitemap.php en la raíz del proyecto, y lo subo por FTP.

En htaccess he incluido el siguiente código:

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ sitemap\.php [L]
```

Y en robots.txt el siguiente:

```
Sitemap: http://miweb.com/sitemap.xml
```

En miweb.com tengo el dominio de mi web.

¿Estoy haciendo algo mal?

La única duda que tengo es que en el fichero robots.txt tengo un error:

```
User-agent: Twitterbot
Disallow: * //aquí el error
```

Pero es otra pregunta que quiero hacer en otro post.

Edito para agregar el código que tengo en el sitemap:

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
echo "<urlset xmlns='http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9'
        xmlns:news='http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-news/0.9'>";

    require 'admin/config.php';
    require 'funciones.php';

    try {
        $conexion = new PDO($bd_config['dbname'], $bd_config['usuario'], $bd_config['password'] );
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        header ('Location: error.php');
        echo "ERROR: ".$e->getMessage();
        die();
    }

    //código

echo "</urlset>\n";

?>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir tu sitemap.php? Me estoy imaginando dónde está el problema pero haría falta ver cómo generas el sitemap con PHP

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si vas al sitemap directamente desde el navegador? ¿Se dibuja bien? Hay al menos un error en el código que haría que se generara un sitemap incorrecto si falla la conexión a la base de datos

Comment: Sí, se muestra bien en principio, lo puedes ver aquí: http://www.laxtore.com/sitemap.php